# Vim from terminal can locate package, GVim cannot

Tags: linux, vim, path, gvim

So I've been installing [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) and [JSHint](http://jshint.com/install/) for some Vim JavaScript syntax checking.

`which jshint` returns `/home/myUser/local/bin/jshint`

`which vim` and `which gvim` return `/usr/bin/vim` and /usr/bin/gvim` respectively.

If I open a JS file from `myUser`'s terminal, Syntastic works fine - :SyntasticInfo returns

```
Syntastic version: 3.5.0-72
Info for filetype: javascript
Mode: active
Filetype javascript is active
Available checker: jshint
Currently enabled checker: jshint
```

However, if I open the same file with GVim, JSHint is not loaded.

```
Syntastic version: 3.5.0-72
Info for filetype: javascript
Mode: active
Filetype javascript is active
Available checker: -
Currently enabled checker: -
```

This makes sense given that if I run `:!which jshint` from vim in the terminal, I get a path and if I run it from GVim I get `shell returned 1`.

I poked around and noticed that JsHint is not loaded in command line Vim if I `sudo su root` and then run `vim`.  Conversely, JSHint **is** loaded if I open GVim as my current user `gksudo -u uname -l "gvim"`.

I'm assuming this means that I somehow need to get `/home/myUser/local/bin/jshint` on my root `$PATH`, but I don't know if this is possible or recommended.

Comment: Just don't work as root, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PATH` is not a global shell variable that you should expect to be the same for all users. You could make it so but that would be pointless: if you want some program to be usable by every user, install it as root.

And… root is used for administrative tasks, ***not*** actual work (unless you are a sysadmin but you are not), so *don't work as root.*

Comment: so GVim and similar should not be installed with `sudo`?

Comment: Installed as root? yes. Used as root? no. Except for administrative tasks. Editing JavaScript is *not* an administrative task so there's no reason whatsoever to do that as root.